# What is the recommended whitespace for slicing with expression indices in Python?

Tags: python, coding-style, whitespace

Examples of slicing in [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) only show integer literals and variables used as indices, not more complex expressions (e.g. `myarray[x/3+2:x/2+3:2]`). PEP-8 also doesn't cover this case. What is the usual usage of whitespace here: `myarray[x/3+2:x/2+3:2]`, `myarray[x/3+2 : x/2+3 : 2]`, or `myarray[x/3+2: x/2+3: 2]` (there don't seem to be other reasonable options)?

Comment: Well, I normally have spaces around my operators, and I would parenthesize the complex expressions: `myarray[(x / 3 + 2):(x / 2 + 3):2]`.

Comment: PEP8 recommends a space around mathematical operators.

Comment: @WaleedKhan changed ; https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#other-recommendations

Comment: @BurhanKhalid changed ; peps.python.org/pep-0008/#other-recommendations

Comment: @SmartManoj The question specifically says PEP-8 doesn't seem to cover this case. If you think it does, please be more specific!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have never seen spaces used in slicing operations, so would err on the side of avoiding them.  Then again, unless it's performance critical I'd be inclined to move the expressions outside of the slicing operation altogether.  After all, your goal is readability:

```
lower = x / 3 + 2
upper = x / 2 + 3
myarray[lower:upper:2]
```

Comment: And if it *is* performance critical then I'd use Cython for it instead.

Comment: Changed ; https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#other-recommendations

Answer (score 3):

I believe the most relevant extract of PEP8 on this subject is:

> The guidelines provided here are intended to improve the **readability** of code and make it consistent across the wide spectrum of Python code.

In this case, my personal choice would probably be either Steve Mayne's answer, or perhaps:

```
myarray[slice(x / 3 + 2, x / 2 + 3, 2)]
```

Comment: Changed;  https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#other-recommendations

Answer (score 1):

[Rule 1. Pet Peeves](https://black.vercel.app/?version=stable&state=_Td6WFoAAATm1rRGAgAhARYAAAB0L-Wj4ABjAEhdAD2IimZxl1N_WmBpTlsra_OPGk7y6cvneEXnLk0KxWo8Zgb0rsPUrgxma5Bh8dioLV0HQwoW8hfZ1-w61mkteTefj1C6iBvDAAC50EzQkg2MFgABZGTJvshrH7bzfQEAAAAABFla)

> However, in a slice the colon acts like a binary operator, and should
> have equal amounts on either side (treating it as the operator with
> the lowest priority). In an extended slice, both colons must have the
> same amount of spacing applied. Exception: when a slice parameter is
> omitted, the space is omitted:

[Rule 2. Other Recommendations](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#:%7E:text=If%20operators%20with,b%29%20*%20%28a-b%29)

If operators with different priorities are used, consider adding whitespace around the operators with the lowest priority(ies). Use your own judgment; however, never use more than one space, and always have the same amount of whitespace on both sides of a binary operator:

The following fails rule 2.

```
myarray[x/3+2:x/2+3:2]
myarray[x/3+2:x/2+3:2]
myarray[x/3+2 : x/2+3 : 2]
myarray[x/3+2: x/2+3: 2]
```

So the answer is,

```
myarray[x/3 + 2 : x/2 + 3 : 2]
```

[Black Playground link](https://black.vercel.app/?version=stable&state=_Td6WFoAAATm1rRGAgAhARYAAAB0L-Wj4ABjAEhdAD2IimZxl1N_WmBpTlsra_OPGk7y6cvneEXnLk0KxWo8Zgb0rsPUrgxma5Bh8dioLV0HQwoW8hfZ1-w61mkteTefj1C6iBvDAAC50EzQkg2MFgABZGTJvshrH7bzfQEAAAAABFla) [Bug](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/1859)